# Consulta en PostgreSQL con filtro en 2 columnas diferentes

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo un problema al hacer un select con filtros a varias columnas.
Tengo una tabla con diferentes grupos de edades (dias, meses, años)
y necesito hacer una consulta donde solo me traiga las personas que los años sean menores a 2 pero los meses sean mayores a 5 es decir las personas con 6 meses de edad a 1 año.

```
select * 
from dean_eapg.v_cuenta_total_evaluados
where  edad = '1'
or (meses > '5' and meses < '12')
```

He intentado con este query y no me funciona.

Comment: y además de tener esos datos en columnas separadas, los guardas como string en vez de número?

Comment: ¿Puedes indicar qué base de datos específica estas usando? La sintaxis para la respuesta puede variar dependiendo de cuál sea tu base de datos (y qué funciones tenga definida)

Comment: si el diseñador de la bbdd los creo tipo string eso influye en la consulta?

Comment: y que es lo que no funciona?? si estan como string, siento decirte que 12 es menor que 5...

Comment: @AngelGutierrez claro que influye, ya que `'5'` es mayor que `'12'`, por lo que `(meses > '5' and meses < '12')` nunca se cumplirá

Comment: ok bueno yo podria ajustar eso en una vista y colocar el tip de dato integer, y estoy trabajando con postgres

Comment: ¿No tienes una columna digamos `fecha_nacimiento` que sea del tipo `DATETIME`? A partir de esa columna podrás hacer un cálculo exacto de la edad, de otro modo vas a tener muchos problemas, con los cálculos y con las comparaciones, como ya estás teniendo. Si guardas la edad en la base de datos misma, también el costo de mantenimiento será grande. Supongamos que una persona entra dentro de tu criterio hoy, pero mañana no porque cumpleaños mañana... Hacer el cálculo desde la fecha de nacimiento te dará siempre los datos exactos, sin tener que ir cambiando la edad manualmente.

Answer (score 1):

> necesito hacer una consulta donde solo me traiga las personas que los
>   años sean menores a 2 pero los meses sean mayores a 5 
>   es decir las personas con 6 meses de edad a 1 año.

Según lo que describes, quieres las personas desde 6 meses de edad (años = 0 y meses >= 6) hasta un año (años = 1 y meses = 0). **Supongo** que una persona que tiene **exactamente** un año puede describirse tanto como (años = 1 y meses = 0) o como (años = 0 y meses = 12).

En ese caso sería:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dean_eapg.v_cuenta_total_evaluados
WHERE  (edad::integer = 1 AND meses::integer = 0) -- exactamente 1 año
OR (edad::integer = 0 AND meses::integer > 5) -- 0 años y 6 a 12 meses
```

Answer (score 1):

Este problema se puede simplificar a la realización de un cálculo entre `edad` (que entiendo que son años) y `meses`, para luego recuperar a las personas que tengan entre 6 y 12 meses de edad.

Algo como:

```
select * 
  from dean_eapg.v_cuenta_total_evaluados
 where (edad::integer * 12 + meses::integer) between 6 and 12
```

OJO, que si tienes otra columna con días, esto aún te va a traer a las personas que tengan un año y algunos cuantos días.